# Summary statistics of retail prices grouped by categorical data

Tags: r

I need some help writing a function that takes three categorical inputs and returns a vector of summary statistics based on these inputs.

The data set contains information on retail goods that can be specified by their retail segment, brand name, and type of good along with its retail price and what it actually sold for.

Now I need to write a function that will take these inputs and average, count, and calculate whatever else is needed.

I have set the function up as follows (using made up data):

```
dataold = data.frame(segment=c("golf","tenis","football","tenis","golf","golf"),
                   brand=c("x","y","z","y","x","a"),
                   type=c("iron","ball","helmet","shoe","driver","iron"),
                   retail=c(124,.60,80,75,150,108),
                   actual=c(112,.60,72,75,135,100))

retailsum = funtion(segment,brand,type){    
     datanew = dataold[which(dataold$segment='segment' & 
                             dataold$brand='brand' & 
                             dataold$type='type'),c("retail","actaul")]

     summary = c(dim(datanew)[1],colMeans(datanew))
     return(summary)
}
```

The code inside the function braces works on its own, but once I wrap a function around it I start getting errors or it will just return `0` counts and `NaN` for the means.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I have very little experience in R, so I apologize if this is a trivial question, but I have not been able to find a solution.

Comment: You'll likely find it helpful to look at the `subset()` function. Also note R uses two "equals" signs, i.e. `==` to indicate equalities.

Comment: You may also want to make sure that it is `function()` in your original script (not "funtion()"). And that you type "actual" instead of "actaul"...

Answer (score 7):

There are rather a lot of errors in your code, including:

- misspelling of `function`
- using single `=` (assignment) rather than `==` (equality test)
- mistype of `actual`
- hardcoding of `segment`, `brand` and `type` in your function, rather than referencing the arguments.

This is how your function *could* look like, i.e. it produces valid results:

```
retailsum <- function(data, segment,brand,type, FUN=colMeans){    
  x = with(data, data[segment==segment && brand==brand && type==type,
                      c("retail","actual")])
  match.fun(FUN)(x)
}

retailsum(dataold, "golf", "x", "iron", colMeans)
  retail   actual 
89.60000 82.43333
```

---

And here is a (possibly much more flexible) solution using the `plyr` package. This calculates your function for all combinations of segment, brand and type:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(dataold, .(segment, brand, type), colwise(mean))
   segment brand   type retail actual
1 football     z helmet   80.0   72.0
2     golf     a   iron  108.0  100.0
3     golf     x driver  150.0  135.0
4     golf     x   iron  124.0  112.0
5    tenis     y   ball    0.6    0.6
6    tenis     y   shoe   75.0   75.0
```

Comment: I apologize for all the spelling errors. This is just a quick example I made up for the post. The actual code is on my work computer.  This code seems to keep returning the column means of the old data set no matter what combination I add to the inputs.  I want the function to return only the mean of the subset created by the inputs I enter.  Am i missing something in the code?  Also, why use with over which?  I am new to the with function and seems to do the same thing. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Andrie's solution is pretty complete already. (`ddply` is cool! Didn't know about that function...)

Just one addition, though: If you want to compute the summary values over all possible combinations, you can do this as a one-liner using R's onboard function `by`:

```
by(dataold, list(dataold$segment, dataold$brand, dataold$type), 
       function(x) summary(x[,c('retail', 'actual')])
)
```

That is not strictly what you asked for, but may still be instructive.